# wget using git credentials

Tags: git, authentication, wget

How do I run `wget` or `curl` to download a single file from a Git repository which is already authenticated in Git?

It seems that I need to pass a private key or a public key, but I am already authenticated in this Git repository using Git credentials manager, so why do I need to pass the private key?

I want to run the command without having to pass the key. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The `wget` and `curl` commands will not use the keys you may have in `.git-credentials` or in the local store helper.

So, in order to download a file from a private GitHub repo directly, you'll need to get a [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) and then download like this:

```
wget --header 'Authorization: token {your access token here}' https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{yourGitHubAccount}/{yourRepo}/main/path/to/file
```

**Important:**

- be sure to replace `{your access token here}` with your Personal Access Token (remember that Tokens are repository specific)
- be sure to replace `{youGitHubAccount}` with your GitHub account name
- be sure to replace `{yourRepo}` with the repository name
- be sure to replace `/main/path/to/file` with the proper branch and path

If you do this often, you can wrap all of this in a shell script to save time.